# using Expression to create a SQLBuilder

Tags: c#, expression

I am wondering if someone could explain for me if it possible to create a Expression like this:

```
sqlBuilder<table1> b=new sqlBuilder<table1>(); 
var sql= b.select(column=>column.Column1,column.Column2)
          .Where(column=>column.Key=="1")
          .OrderBy(column=>column.column1);
```

the sql variable will store a select statement in string like this:

```
SELECT column1,column2 From table1 WHERE key='1' OrderBy column1
```

Comment: Maybe you should look at ORMs? Entity Framework, NHibernate and etc

Comment: I want build own sql builder engine using expression.